# Printing c char* from inline assembly using int 10h

Tags: c++, assembly

I am trying below code to print c `char*` from inline assembly

```
extern "C" void KernelMain()
{
    char    *mytxt = "Ahmed";
    _asm
    {
            mov     si,mytxt

        Print:
            lodsb                           ; load next character
            or      al, al                  ; test for NUL character
            jz      DONE
            mov     ah, 00Eh                ; BIOS teletype
            mov     bh, 000h                ; display page 0
            mov     bl, 007h                ; text attribute
            int     010h                    ; invoke BIOS
            jmp     Print
        DONE :
    }
```

but while debugging I always find `si` refer to wrong offset.
I have tried `mov si,offset mytxt` and it also failed.

i am using mscv++

Comment: You should specify which C compiler you're using.

Comment: Which compiler are you using ? You could try to use the `lea` instruction instead of the mov: `lea si, mytxt`

Comment: i have tried lea si,mytxt also refer to wrong offset!

Comment: A 16-bit, real-mode MSVC?

Comment: msvc++ coming with visual studio 2013

Comment: Can 32-bit console programs run 16-bit binaries like this? I doubt that MSVC can even compile 16-bit programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char    *mytxt = "Ahmed";
```

This is a pointer to the text, `mytext` doesn't contain the text itself, just the address of the text.

```
        mov     si,mytxt
```

This loads the address of `mytext` into `si`, which is where the pointer is stored, not the pointer itself.

You can load the content of `mytext`, which is the address of the string, by using

```
        mov     si,[mytxt]
```

where `[]` indicates an indirection. Load the value stored at `mytext`.